# Android: ClassNotFoundException while including ZXing

Tags: android, cordova, zxing

I know there are a lot of questions already. I've been going through all of them, but still I`m not able to solve my issue.

I was asked to extend an already existing android app, which is based on `PhoneGap`. I checked out the sources from a repo, and realized that the first developer included some `library` as `dependency`. i followed the instructions [here](http://www.androiddevelopersolution.com/2012/06/integrating-zxing-qr-code-scanner-into.html), build in the `core` of `ZXing` isn't any `build.xml`for `ant`.

I went through the instructions at [XZing Getting started](http://www.androiddevelopersolution.com/2012/06/integrating-zxing-qr-code-scanner-into.html), build my own `core-2.3.jar` tried to include, but failed. Same with the ready-deployed `core.jar` from the page

I included the the jars in the `/libs` folder, imported is a `external jar`, nothing worked. I`m getting following error everytime:

```
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{dev.tesobe.mobilepayment/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" on path: /data/app/dev.tesobe.mobilepayment-1.apk
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" on path: /data/app/dev.tesobe.mobilepayment-1.apk
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
07-24 17:09:47.554: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
```

The manifest-declaration looks like this:

```
<!-- ZXing activities --> 
    <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" 
            android:exported="false"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 
    <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" 
        android:label="@string/share_name"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE"/> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

So, anyone any ideas, why I'm not able to include the `CaptureActivity`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should ensure:

- The ZXing Library is Added to your libs directory
- Import the ZXing library in the properties/Build path
- Ensure -- and this is the important part -- in the tab "Order and Export" that the Android Private Libraries is activated.

Normally, with the last Eclipse Android Plugins all this proccess is automatic when paste a jar inside the libs directory but there are some problems when add new libraries in old proyects. Try to enable the android private libraries.

ExtraBall: If you only want to capture barcodes you can try this fork of Zxing with the only indispensable of ZXing http://code.google.com/p/android-zxinglib/

Comment: hi aracem, thanks for answer. i just realized, that the project needed the XZing Phonegap Plugin, not the XZing Library...

Answer (score -1):

**ISSUE SOLVED**

Well... Stupid mistake. In the end I realized, that I didn't need to include the `XZing Library jar`. The guy who started the project included the `PhoneGap Barcode Scanner Plugin` which can be found [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner). Followed the instructions and everything is working well...

Comment: it's not crearly specified anywhere that this plugin includes XZing lib.